# How to resolve BadHostKeyException with paramiko?

Tags: python, linux, paramiko, ssh-keys

I have following code to connect to a linux box and run a command, But I'm facing
BadHostKeyException even after I have added `WarningPolicy` and `AutoAddPolicy`.

```
            print("---CCCCCCCCCCCCC---",commands)
            client = paramiko.SSHClient()
            client.load_system_host_keys()
            client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy)
            client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            client.connect(ipAddress, port=22, username=sshUser, password=sshPassword)
            self.logger.info("executeOnRemoteShell - Created SSH connection to " + ipAddress)
            stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(commands)
            result = str(stdout.readlines()[0].rstrip())
```

not sure what I'm missing here, below is the full error.

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.BadHostKeyException: Host key for server '45.32.23.23' does not match: got 'AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBGcWA6JnHBbVIGsdC+USD2GOxWNy+R8hiiFiLse75rs1JRTWN8i3ol3yZ4OhFhQl4upZ7f5/scFzw4DqoMrhRIE=', expected 'AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBJSELS2mT8SED8I7QFf5YkkvD5n4LCHUkX4ykeemwuqGHOBVHixQMBtKWF9lFuKFhKOCNsifRPK1FfkT23glapI
```

Comment: a bad host key is not the same as a missing one. it usually means that the server key changed or that whatever you tell your client the host key was is inaccurate. The long stuff in the error msg are b64 encoded names of those keys, both ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, but different keys

Answer (score -2):

Quick reply:

According to a discussion on [github](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1045) the solution may be to get rid of  `client.load_system_host_keys()`

> If you're using SSHClient connect(), then don't call load_host_keys(),

See in the [paramiko docs](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/3.4/api/client.html) regarding `load_system_host_keys`:

> If filename is left as None, an attempt will be made to read keys from
> the user’s local “known hosts” file, as used by OpenSSH, and no
> exception will be raised if the file can’t be read.

I had this issue in the past. For instance, if you have a server and normally use some SSH connection, which means that in your known_hosts file, the expected identity will be stored, but then you to connect via paramiko, to a different SSH server on the server - for instance the paramiko one - then your paramiko client (due to the use of the "load_system_host_keys" line), uses the data known from the regular SSH server for identification, and those keys may not match. I solved this by not using anything from the regular SSH processes and created keys (on both sides) for paramiko only.

More generally, `paramiko.ssh_exception.BadHostKeyException` doesn't mean the host key is missing, but that it either changed or that whatever your client thinks the host key should have been, is inaccurate. It's a security measure to protect against Man-In-The-Middle attack scenarios. The long strings in the error message are base64 encoded non-ascii versions of what your client expected and what the host offers.